# Android Compose on button click go to sleep (turn screen off)

Tags: android, kotlin, sleep-mode, screen-off, android-jetpack-compose-button

Like title said how to on click button to go system sleep, to turn off screen?

got this kotlin code:

```
@Composable
fun ButtonOnClickGoToSystemSleep() {
    // Fetching the Local Context
    val localContext = LocalContext.current

    Button(onClick = {
        val intent = Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN")
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", true)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        localContext.startActivity(intent)
    }) {
        Text(text = "Go to sleep",Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp))
    }
```

By the way this is not working, got this from stackoverflow 5 or 10 years ago..

Comment: https://9to5answer.com/turn-off-screen-on-android